# How to correct the pagenumber of a \section* in the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents

In my book I have two starred sections into a starred chapter.  When I include the chapter in ToC with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter title}
```

the displayed pagenumber is correct.  When I do the same for the first section of that chapter everything is ok (because the are in the same page)

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{First Section title}
```

but when I do it for the second starred section

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Second Section title}
```

its pagenumber in the Toc is displayed wrong (it's displayed the same page as the chapter and first section).

How can I correct the pagenumber of that second starred secion in the ToC?

I'm using the book class.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

This a MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section Zero}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second Chapter}
\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{First Section}
\section*{First Section}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Second Section}
\section*{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

And it works!!!!!  The problem is that it doesn't work if I add the chapters by `\include` instead of `\chapter`

Comment: Put the lines directly after the \section* they belong to.

Comment: Hi, Johannes.  It didn't work.

Comment: That means we need to see a minimal working example to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have a problem to provide a MWE: they work when you add chapters by **\chapter** command but they fail when you add them with **\include** command.  So, there is no way to give you a MWE.

Comment: Then at least i have to wait until my crystal ball is back from the shop. It is currently broken.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Well, difficult to foretell when your crystal ball  will be back from the repair without having, well, a crystal ball ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by `add chapters by `\include`? `\include` does not add chapters except of having `\chapter` in the included file

Comment: The `\addcontentsline` macro should be after `\section*`, not before...

Comment: Putting it after? Sounds familiar.

Comment: By the way, package `blindtext` helps you in gettting page of dummy text while keeping the code very short. I bet you can coe up with an MWE that way.

Comment: @Johannes_B: You should also refer to `unnumberedtotoc`!

Comment: Hi.  I undertand your jokes!!  Finally I could solve the problem: I putted **\addcontentsline...** before (not after) every **\section** and it worked.  I don't know why it did't do it the last time.  So, the solution was to put **\addcontentsline...** in the file where the chapter is.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Fabio: Placing `\addcontentsline` *before* `\chapter*` or `\section*` does not make sense. It will have to be *after*.

Comment: @Fabio -- if you use `\include`, it will always start a new page.  that is why, when `\addcontentsline` is in the `\include`d file the page number for a chapter will be correct.  even so, the `\addcontentsline` should *always* come after the `\chapter` (or `\section`, etc.) line so that it can't be separated by a page break from the heading that is to appear in the toc.